# ResizingArrayStack vs. LinkedStack

Tags: java, abstract-data-type

We are supposed to explain which datatype is faster. In my Opinion the LinkedStack should be way faster but after we did some testing in Java the tests showed no big differences if not the contrary. We can't explain this at all.

So which datatype should be faster and why?

```java
        ResizingArrayStack resizingArrayStack = new ResizingArrayStack();
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            resizingArrayStack.push("test");
        }

        StdOut.printf("(%.8f milliseconds in Array)\n", stopwatch.elapsedTime());


        LinkedStack linkedStack = new LinkedStack();
        Stopwatch stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            linkedStack.push("test");
        }
        StdOut.printf("(%.8f milliseconds in Linked)\n", stopwatch1.elapsedTime());
```

gives this output:

```
(1063.87700000 milliseconds in Array)
(1610.73700000 milliseconds in Linked)
```

Comment: Share your example and we might be able to point out the reason you see no differences.

Comment: Did you do the testing using [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)?

Comment: What do you mean by faster? Insertion, removal, searching, what?

Comment: @DavidBaak I edited the post to contain a sample.